# Even admin cant register ASP.NET 4

Tags: windows, windows-7, asp.net, iis-7.5

When I try running the following command, logged in as admin, I get the accompanying error:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -i

An error has occurred: 0x8007b799
You must have administrative rights on this machine in order to run this tool.
```

WTF?  How many more admin rights do you get than an admin user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command has to be run from an elevated command prompt, not just the normal command prompt. Even Admin needs to explicitly run an elevated prompt to do certain things.

Comment: Right click on CMD link Start menu and select "Run as Administrator".